# How to center multiple JLabels on one JPanel and how to set the labels text orientation to centered

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to make a JPanel in which text is displayed on two JLabels like a movie or book title.

How can I set two labels to be centered on one JPanel (one above and one below)?
Also, is there any way to set the text alignment within the JLabel to centered like when writing a title to a document, book or movie. (author and title are centered headers)

EDIT: This should remain true in fullscreen mode.

EXAMPLE:

```
               JLabel1
          Jlabel2withlongertext
```

Comment: Use a single column `GridLayout` for stacking the labels.  Use one of the [label constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#constructor.summary) that accepts an `horizontalAlignment` in order to center the text.

Comment: I used setLayout on my panel with GridLayout and added SwingConstants.CENTER in the label constructors but this resulted in both labels being centered in one line. I need to get one label above and one below.

Comment: `GridLayout` is not limited to horizontal rows, that's just the default with the no-arguments constructor. Use `new GridLayout(0, 1)` for a single column grid with unspecified amount of rows.

Comment: @kiheru Thank you, this works. Please post your comment as answer if you would like to receive credit for it.

Comment: I feel it's more @AndrewThompson's answer than mine. I just added a detail about the constructor parameters. He already had all the building blocks for a working solution in his comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*OK, adding an answer so that others don't waste time here:*

As pointed out by Andrew, this can be achieved by combining [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) which can be used to create a column of the labels, and setting the text alignment in the labels themselves:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
// Setting rows to 0 means that new rows are added as needed
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
panel.add(new JLabel("text", SwingConstants.CENTER));
panel.add(new JLabel("longer text", SwingConstants.CENTER));
```

GridLayout makes the labels both the same size, so centering the text inside the labels also centers them relative to each other.